# PHP - For each loop last forever

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

I have array of integers. I need to group that integer using specific algorithm that is working well. problem is that I stuck in forever loop.

I created algorithm that compares two elements of array with some number and when statement is true, that two elements are removed from array.

For each loop is surrounded with while loop that check if array is empty (it stops when all elements are removed) and that for each loop  is used to compare array elements with specific number like mentioned above.

Does someone knows what's wrong with my code

CODE:

```
$testArray1=array(2,1,4,7,1,2,6,8);
$group=3;
sort($testArray1);
$arrlength = count($testArray1);
$totalnumber=0;
for($x = 0; $x <  $arrlength; $x++) {
     $totalnumber+= $testArray1[$x];
}
$groupNumber = round($totalnumber/$group,0);
while (!empty($testArray1)) {
$arrlength = count($testArray1);

foreach($testArray1 as $key => &$val) {
    $end=end($testArray1);
    $number=$val+$end;
     if ($number==$groupNumber){
        echo $val." , "." , ".$end.": ".$number. "<br>";
        unset ($testArray1[$key]);
        array_pop($testArray1);
        break;

     }
}
}
?>
```

HERE IS WHAT I REALLY NEED TO DO:

let's say I have array like this:

```
array(2,1,4,7,1,2,6,8);
```

I need to write a algorithm that receives two parameters (array of integers and the number of groups). That array needs to be divided in number of group that user define in a way that the sum of all the members within each group as close as possible.

Here is example:

I have array like this: 2, 1, 4, 7, 2, 6, 8 and I need to divide it into 3 groups.

After this array is divided into groups, my output needs to look like this:

GROUP 1: 8,2 : 10
GROUP 2: 7,2,1 : 10
GROUP 3: 6, 4, 1: 11

Comment: uhm... if you put this &$val to this ? $val it change something? That said tried editing this !empty($testArray1) with if (count($testArray1) > 0){} ?

Comment: "is working well. problem is that I stuck in forever loop. " your definition of *working well* is a little odd

Comment: @MarcoMura I tried your suggestion... Now it wont even load page :(

Comment: @Dagon algorithm is working nice. I have problems with loop and arrays

Comment: What do you think your algorithm is actually doing?  I don't think it is working as you suspect.

Comment: @MikeBrant I edited code that shows what I need to do

Comment: This sounds like an interview question. :)

Comment: @MikeBrant yes it is. I have done it using math on paper... but I can't find solution using PHP

Comment: I don't think your algorithm is right.  Have you considered using two array pointers, one incrementing from start and one decrementing from end?

Comment: @MikeBrant you can do that as you suggested but you cant be sure that each group will be close as possible

Comment: You also are not handling edge conditions well.  What if one of the array values is greater than the average group value you are shooting for ($groupNumber)? What value is there in even determining the average group sum (`$groupNumber`)? For example, what if your array was (2,1,4,7,1,2,6,1000)?

Comment: @user3429355 You can actually do that, you just mayx need to look ahead and behind the pointers respectively to determine the best combination.   Take that example array I gave. How does your algorithm address that case?

Comment: I just ask these questions as I am EXTREMELY familiar with conducting these sorts of interviews and I see you failing on points that I would be looking to pick up on.

Comment: Make sure and ask clarifying question here as this problem is actually fairly difficult to solve depending on whether the sum of the groups need to be both as close in sum as well as in member count to each other.  In other words, can there be a group of one element and 2 groups of 3 or 4. These sort of question make a difference in your approach and a good interviewer is looking for you to ask these clarifying questions.

Comment: @MikeBrant well if you use numbers that you suggest in previous comment you just cant detect edge conditions because it's number difference is large and you can't do nothing about it...

Answer (score 0):

In short, your loop is infinite because the while condition can never be true.

I refactored your code a little to limit how much you are manipulating the array while you are looping through it.  I did this by moving the array out of the while condition and moving the end out of the foreach (which was safe to do since you were calling a break).  I added a break 2 just to illustrate why it's freezing.

```
<?php
$testArray1=array(2,1,4,7,1,2,6,8);
$group=3;
sort($testArray1);
$arrlength = count($testArray1);
$totalnumber=0;
for($x = 0; $x <  $arrlength; $x++) {
     $totalnumber+= $testArray1[$x];
}
$groupNumber = round($totalnumber/$group,0);
$length = count( $testArray1 );
while ( $length > 0 ) {
    $end=end($testArray1); // get the last element's value
    var_dump( $testArray1 );

    foreach($testArray1 as $key => $val) {
        $number=$val+$end;
        if ($number==$groupNumber){
            echo $key." - ".$val." , "." , ".$end.": ".$number. "<br>";
            unset ($testArray1[$key]);
            array_pop( $testArray1 );
            $length -= 2;
            break 2;
        }
    }
}
echo "<br /><br />length: ".$length;
echo "<br /><br />";
var_dump( $testArray1 );
?>
```

After the first while loop iteration, the array that is left has 7 at the end.  But the values that need to add up to 10 off of 7 are 1, 4, and 6.  Obviously none of those add to 7.

```
array(8) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(1) [2]=> int(2) [3]=> int(2) [4]=> int(4) [5]=> int(6) [6]=> int(7) [7]=> int(8) } 2 - 2 , , 8: 10


length: 6

array(6) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(1) [3]=> int(2) [4]=> int(4) [5]=> int(6) [6]=> int(7) }
```

You've got to change something fundamental.  For example, recalculate the group number for each iteration of the loop.

Other notes...
If you're going to use lowercase, use all lower case.  If you're going to use camel back, use all camel back.  Be consistent.  It is annoying to have to look up if totalnumber & arrlength are capitalized or not.

Comment: Thank you for answer @phpmeh . Your code is working but only one loop is done. I need to loop over and over until all elements are deleted

Comment: This code will never delete all of the elements, which is why I stopped it with the break 2 to show why it will never delete all of the elements.  I recommended how to fix it as well.  It's as easy as moving the totalnumber code blocks into the while loop.  Also, look into array_sum.